# Firebase Admin NodeJS SDK: TenantAwareAuth.createSessionCookie() throws unsupported tenant operation

Tags: node.js, firebase, multi-tenant, firebase-admin, google-identity

When implementing a tenant aware auth instance using Firebase Admin SDK I cannot use the [following method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.auth.tenantawareauth.md#tenantawareauthcreatesessioncookie).

**Code:**

```
    // defined elsewhere: locals.tenantAuth = getAuth().tenantManager().authForTenant(tenantId)

    async createSession (locals) {
    try {
      const { idToken, expiresIn, tenantAuth } = locals
      const decodedToken = await tenantAuth.verifyIdToken(idToken, true) // this works
      // Only process if the user just signed in in the last 3 minutes
      if (new Date().getTime() / 1000 - decodedToken.auth_time < 3 * 60) {
        return await tenantAuth.createSessionCookie(idToken, { expiresIn }) // this breaks
      } else {
        throw new Error('Cannot create session, sign in information is too old')
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      throw new Error(error)
    }
  }
```

**Error:**

```
FirebaseAuthError: This operation is not supported in a multi-tenant context.
errorInfo: {
  code: 'auth/unsupported-tenant-operation',
  message: 'This operation is not supported in a multi-tenant context.'
},
codePrefix: 'auth'
```

**Version:**

- Nodejs: 16.13.0
- Firebase Admin SDK: 10.0.0

**Additional:**

- Method works outside of tenantAware auth (using default project `getAuth()`)
- Same error on v9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already submitted as a feature request. You may check its status through this submitted [feature request link](https://issuetracker.google.com/204377229).

You may want to check this [Stack Overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59065210/how-to-generate-firebase-custom-tokens-in-multi-tenant-setup/59274537#59274537) as a workaround.